# Preventing form submit based on entering the same numbers in the box input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I have an input box here

```
<input type="text" size="9" maxlength="9" id="my_account" name="my_account" value="" >
```

and here I am disallowing users to enter the same numbers in the box, but what I really want is to prevent the form submit instead

```
var inputNode = document.getElementById('my_account');

inputNode.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  var inputValue = event.key;
  var inputNodeValue = inputNode.value;
  var length = inputNodeValue.length;

  if (length === 3 && inputNodeValue[0] === inputValue) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

this is my form prevent default

```
$("form#customer-summary").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("prevent submit");             
});
```

How can I combine these two parts so I dont allow users to submit same numbers in the box ?

Comment: Put the code in a named function that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the field is valid. Then you can call it in the `keydown` and `submit` handlers.

Comment: ^ do that, but you're going to have to figure out another way to check if there are multiples of the same number in the input, as you won't be able to just check the keystrokes

Comment: _"and here I am disallowing users to enter the same numbers in the box"_ Do you mean that values input must be unique?

Comment: either numbers like 111 or 222 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputNode = document.getElementById('my_account');
var customer_summary = document.getElementById('customer-summary');
customer_summary.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
   if(!is_unique(inputNode.value)){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("prevent submit");
   }             
});

    function is_unique(val){
       for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
           if(val.indexOf(val.charAt(i)) != val.lastIndexOf(val.charAt(i))){
              return false;
           }       
       }
      return true;
    }
```

I think this should do the trick. Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m31h1zhg/2/.

Comment: was it your requirement ?